# How to edit headers/footers from a document using PHPWord?

Tags: php, phpword

I am using PHPWord to create documents. What I need to do is edit the header/footer content of an existing docx/odt document. It was not very hard to add the content to a document. But I've spent the whole day on the internet to find a solution. Here is the code through which I am only being able to add content to existing header/footer content:

```
$source = "DumpFiles/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($source);
    echo "File Loaded";

    // Get Sections from the imported document...
    $sections = $phpWord->getSections();
    $section = $sections[0];

    // Adding Header and Footer Content
    if(isset($_POST['headerContent']) && $_POST['headerContent']!=null)
    {
        $headert = $section->createHeader();
        $table = $headert->addTable();
        $table->addRow();
        $table->addCell(4500)->addText($_POST['headerContent']);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['footerContent']) && $_POST['footerContent'])
    {
        $footervar = $section->createFooter();
        $table = $footervar->addTable();
        $table->addRow();
        $table->addCell(4500)->addText($_POST['footerContent']);
    }
```

I understand that the usage of `global` variables directly is a bad practice. :-p

I would rectify these discrepancies in my code once I get the existing code working.

A solution with an example would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the existing header contents in the following way (simplified to make it shorter, i.e. missing all existence and type checks):

```
$headers = $section->getHeaders();
$header1 = $headers[1]; // note that the first index is 1 here (not 0)

$elements = $header1->getElements();
$element1 = $elements[0]; // and first index is 0 here normally

// for example manipulating simple text information ($element1 is instance of Text object)
$element1->setText("This is my text addition - old part: " . $element1->getText());
```

Access to the footer data is very similar:

```
$footers = $section->getFooters();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Just tried out your code and it returns the following error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table::setText()`

What could possibly be going wrong?

Comment: That means that the existing (first) header element is a Table object (instead of the example Text object directly), i.e. you just need to alter how you access the data: $element1->getRows() gets you the rows and you just continue onward from that (the details depend on what you actually have there in the header and footer and what parts you want to modify)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions once again. I changed my previous code a bit and got this working. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is this:

```
$PHPWord = new PHPWord();
$section = $PHPWord->createSection();
$header = $section->createHeader();
$header->addImage('images/header.png');
$footer = $section->createFooter();
$footer->addImage('images/footer.png');
```

Comment: getting error `Fatal error: Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method createsection is not defined.` Not worked for me, I am using PHPWORD version 1.0.