# PhpWord add footer to template

Tags: php, phpword

I want to add footer to my created document, how can i do this with phpword?

My template processing code:

```
$template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor("my-template.docx");

$table = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Table();

$table->addRow();
$table->addCell()->addText("test");

$template->setComplexBlock('table_var', $table);

$template->saveAs("new-file.docx");
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30753639/8740349), first **save your template**, and then open the result again like:

```php
$file = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load("new-file.docx");

// Get Sections from the imported document...
$sections = $file->getSections();
$section = $sections[0];
```

Then, if your template does not have any footer, add one like:

```php
$footer1 = $section->createFooter();
$footer1->addImage('images/footer.png');
```

Or, you can edit existing footer like:

```php
// Note that the first index is 1 here (not 0).
$footers = $section->getFooters();
$footer1 = $footers[1];

// And first index is 0 for elements normally.
$elements = $footer1->getElements();
$element1 = $elements[0];

// For example manipulating simple text information ($element1 is instance of Text object)
$element1->setText("My new text, old content: " . $element1->getText());
```

Comment: $template->getSections(); is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, edited try again (after you change the way of opening to the mentioned one).

Comment: I want to add the footer with the TemplateProcessor, because IOFactory::load dumps all formatting on the existing document.

Comment: Could not find the API, but edited to a workaround.

Comment: There is currently an open [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/1085), so either use my workaround or first save template then open result with IOFactory.

Comment: I tried your workaround, but it's not adding the footer and what is the setValue('content') for?